# Como poner negrilla in-line en un texto para un pdf generado com FPDF en python usando una fuente que soporte UTF-8

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf, unicode, markdown

Estoy haciendo un script en python para generar un documento en PDF con FPDF2, tengo un problema a la hora de renderizar este documento, en uno de los párrafos algunas palabras y frases deben ir en **negrilla(bold)**, había logrado solucionar este problema usando **multi-cell** y activando el **MARKDOWN**, todo funcionaba perfecto hasta que en uno de los textos que tengo guardados en un formato .txt que estoy utilizando para hacer el PDF aparece el carácter **“** arrojando el siguiente error:

`fpdf.errors.FPDFUnicodeEncodingException: Character "“" at index 544 in text is outside the range of characters supported by the font  used: "times". Please consider using a Unicode font.`

Lo siguiente que hice fue bajar una fuente de google fonts y agregarla con **add_font()**

```
texto1 = f"""**{nombre}**, mayor de edad, vecino de **{ciudad_usuario}**, identificado con la **{id_tipo}**
 No. **{id_numero}** expedida en **{id_lugar_expedicion}**, actuando con mi propio nombre y ... """
fuente_tipo = "SourceSerifPro-Regular"
class PDF(FPDF):
    def __init__(self):
        # Llamamos al constructor de la clase padre
        # y establecemos el tamaño de la página a carta 
        # y las medidas en milímetros
        FPDF.__init__(self, unit="mm", format="letter", orientation="P")
        # se aniade la fuente de google fonts
        self.add_font("SourceSerifPro-Regular", "", "SourceSerifPro-Regular.ttf")
    
    def header(self):
        # Añadimos una cabecera al documento
        self.set_xy(25, 10)
        self.set_font(fuente_tipo, '', 12)
        self.ln(15)
        self.cell(0, 10, fecha, 0)
        self.ln(15)
    
    def footer(self):
        # Añadimos un pie de página al documento
        self.set_xy(185, -15)
        self.set_font(family= fuente_tipo, size= 8)
        self.cell(0, 10, 'Página ' + str(self.page_no()) + ' de n', 0)

    def add_txt_text(self, route):
        # Abre el archivo "texto.txt" en modo lectura
        with open(route, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            # Lee todo el contenido del archivo y lo almacena en la variable texto
            texto = f.read()
        self.multi_cell(0, None, texto, markdown = True, new_x='LEFT', new_y= 'NEXT')

# Creamos una instancia de la clase PDF
pdf = PDF()
# Establecemos márgenes y deshabilitamos la división automática de páginas
pdf.set_margins(25, 30, 10)
# Aniadimos una página
pdf.add_page()
# para que se creen paginas automaticamente cuando se pasa la margen de bajo
pdf.set_auto_page_break(auto=True, margin=20)
# Establecemos el tipo de letra y tamaño
pdf.set_font(fuente_tipo, '', 12)
# Este es el texto que tiene las negrillas
pdf.multi_cell(0, None,  texto1, markdown = True, new_x='LEFT', new_y= 'NEXT') # max_line_height=30,
# Este es el texto que tiene el caracter “
pdf.add_txt_text('fundamento_juridico.txt')
pdf.output('ejemplo.pdf')
```

FDPF tiene 3 fuentes predeterminadas, las cuales no soportan algunos caracteres de utf-8, al agregar otra funte se arroja el siguiente error.

```
 File "C:\Users\user\Documents\PDF_generator\index.py", line 101, in <module>
    pdf.multi_cell(0, None,  texto1, markdown = True, new_x='LEFT', new_y= 'NEXT') # max_line_height=30,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 216, in wrapper
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 3213, in multi_cell
    styled_text_fragments = self._preload_font_styles(normalized_string, markdown)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 3004, in _preload_font_styles     
    self.set_font(style="B")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1873, in set_font
    raise FPDFException(
fpdf.errors.FPDFException: Undefined font: sourceserifpro-regularB - Use built-in fonts or FPDF.add_font() beforehand
```

Ahora me veo entre eliminar ese tipo de caracteres en los textos que use para generar el pdf, o no poder usar markdown para poder poner en negrilla algunas palabras in-line en algunos textos.
Se aprecia algun consejo o solucion a este problema